# PhpMyAdmin loads infinitely, won't load at all

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, google-compute-engine

I am building a WordPress environment in a google cloud compute engine using the bitnami stack.

PhpMyAdmin has been working fine, however now when I enter its address in chrome, it loads infinitely.

I thought it might be a permissions issue since I was changing that a lot lately, however, I am not sure how to reset the permissions of the folder to Linux default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about this [solution](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/wordpress?q=wordpress%20bitnami&id=3c46fbae-f109-4f39-b9e5-dd5756b86d37) which is available in Cloud Marketplace.

When you setup this solution it is deployed through Google Cloud Deployment, and the GCE instance is using a custom image from Bitnami. However, if you made changes on this application, please check if the original external IP, because if you didn't provide a static external IP, then it may change whenever the GCE instance is restarted.

So, if the external IP changed you will need to fix all the application's path. Otherwise, I think is worth to open a support case with [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/support) and they should be able to guide you to fix this issue.